# Update if not exists, if exists check if code is different from 1 and update

Tags: sql

I'm trying to build a SQL command to update my table

Update a row in `myProduct` if it does not exists in table `order`, or if it exists, check in table `order` if the code is != 1 to update

```
UPDATE myProduct
SET statut = 3
WHERE  
    myProduct_id NOT IN (SELECT myProduct_id
                         FROM order
                         WHERE code != 1
                           AND myProduct.myProduct_id = order.myProduct_id)
    OR NOT EXISTS IN (SELECT myProduct_id FROM order)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code..

```
UPDATE p
    SET statut = 3
FROM myProduct p
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1
        FROM order o
        WHERE code != 1
        AND p.myProduct_id = 0.myProduct_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the logic is:  Update all rows where the corresponding row in `order` is not 1 (or none exists).

If so, you can do this with a simpler statement:

```
UPDATE myProduct p
    SET statut = 3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM orders o
                  WHERE o.code = 1 AND p.myProduct_id = o.myProduct_id);
```

You don't specify the database, but the above is standard SQL.

Note:  `order` is a really bad name for a table, because it is a SQL keyword.  That is why I used `orders` instead of `order`.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE myProduct SET statut = 3
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM order WHERE code != 1 AND myProduct.myProduct_id = order.myProduct_id )